# How to level out or grind down concrete basement floor?

Tags: concrete, basement, flooring, basement-refinishing

I had a french drain installed in my basement and the top of its cement sits around 1/8" to 1/4" of an inch higher then the rest of my basement floor. I need to somehow level this out so I can put flooring down. How would you recommend I do this?

Comment: How does your floor drain if the drain is higher than the floor?

Comment: are you trying to grind down the french drain?

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned this but based on the statement:

> I had a french drain installed

it seems to me like if you paid someone (assumption here) to install a drain and they left it in a state where it is going to cause a puddle to form before water is able to drain into it, that it should be the company's responsibility at this point.  At the very least, you should be contacting them to get their explanation as to why it was done that way before attempting to undo what they did.

Comment: I had the same thought. Seems like a fail.

Answer (score 1):

From the description, I suggest renting a proper [concrete grinder](http://www.homedepot.com/c/concrete_equipment_rental) (bottom of the page) from your local rental shop or big box. This will allow finer control and result in a flatter, smoother surface than if you attempted to use abrasive or diamond-bitted handheld power tools.

If you'd rather not go that far, an angle grinder with an appropriate disk would do the job. You may need to skim the resulting surface to prep it for vinyl tile or other flooring sensitive to surface texture.

Comment: A grinder with a sanding wheel/disk

Comment: If you grind, use a mask. [Silicosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicosis) is no fun.

Answer (score 0):

A big 7" angle grinder with a diamond cup bit would work nicely.  You can also get away with the 'masonry grinding' bit sold at big box stores.  You should try to get a dust shroud as well, as even a small amount of concrete grinding will send fine dust everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small area around the drain, the lowest cost, least-fuss option is one of these grinding blocks (use with some water and you can mop the slurry up rather than deal with dust in the air. Plug the floor drain first.)

[image: silicon carbide grinding block]

The one with the grooves is most applicable.